# Do you say to a kid "Please don't stomp in the puddle. You are splashing my face with the water"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

> [splash](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/splash_1?q=splash) [transitive] to make somebody/something wet by making water, mud, etc.
>   fall on them/it
>
> splash something on/onto/over somebody/something He splashed cold
>   water on his face.
>
> splash somebody/something with something He splashed his face with
>   cold water.
>
> My clothes were splashed with mud.
>
> splash somebody/something Stop splashing me!
>
> Try not to splash the leaves when you water the plant.

Look at the picture

[image]

Your child is stomping in the puddle.

Do you say "**Please don't stomp in the puddle. You are splashing my face with the water**"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a language perspective, "you are splashing my face with the water" is fine.

From a physics perspective, I would think that your face is probably the least likely part of your body to get wet since it's the farthest from the ground where the puddle is.

From a parenting perspective, you might want to not say anything and just let the kid have fun.

Answer (score 1):

What you said is understandable. I think it would more likely be said  this way:
Please don't stamp your feet. You're splashing water in my face!."

So, I think the word "stamp" is more likely than "stomp". It's probably not necessary to mention the puddle, since it is at the center of the action.